# How to write and read Stream using indy 10.5.5 c++

Tags: c++, c++builder, indy10

Hi I have try to read Stream from the server with this code

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1KeyPress(TObject *Sender, wchar_t &Key)
{
   //TMemoryStream *TMS = new TMemoryStream;
   TStringStream *TSS = new TStringStream;
   AnsiString A,B;
   TStream *TS;
   INT64 Len;
   try
   {
       if (Key == VK_RETURN)
       {
          Beep(0,0);
          if(Edit1->Text == "mystream")
           {
               TCPClient1->IOHandler->WriteLn("mystream");
               Len = StrToInt(TCPClient1->IOHandler->ReadLn());
               TCPClient1->IOHandler->ReadStream(TS,Len,false);
               TSS->CopyFrom(TS,0);
               RichEdit1->Lines->Text = TSS->DataString;
               Edit1->Clear();
           }
       else
           {
              TCPClient1->IOHandler->WriteLn(Edit1->Text);
              A = TCPClient1->IOHandler->ReadLn();
              RichEdit1->Lines->Add(A);
              Edit1->Clear();
           }
       }
   }
   __finally
   {
       TSS->Free();
   }

}
```

and every times client try to read stream from the server, compiler says.

```
First chance exception at $75D89617. Exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 500682B3 in module 'rtl140.bpl'. Read of address 00000018'. Process Project1.exe (6056)
```

How to handle this?

Comment: The first thing you should do when getting a crash, is to run your program in a debugger. It will not only help you pinpoint the location of your crash, but also let you examine variables to help you figure out the _reason_ for the crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not instantiating your `TStream` object before calling `ReadStream()`.  Your `TS` variable is completely uninitialized.  `ReadStream()` does not create the `TStream` object for you, only writes to it, so you have to create the `TStream` yourself beforehand.

Given the code you have shown, you can replace the `TStream` completely by using the `ReadString()` method instead:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1KeyPress(TObject *Sender, wchar_t &Key) 
{ 
    if (Key == VK_RETURN) 
    { 
        Beep(0,0); 
        if (Edit1->Text == "mystream") 
        { 
            TCPClient1->IOHandler->WriteLn("mystream"); 
            int Len = StrToInt(TCPClient1->IOHandler->ReadLn()); 
            RichEdit1->Lines->Text = TCPClient1->IOHandler->ReadString(Len); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            TCPClient1->IOHandler->WriteLn(Edit1->Text); 
            String A = TCPClient1->IOHandler->ReadLn(); 
            RichEdit1->Lines->Add(A); 
        } 
        Edit1->Clear(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi MR.Remy
I make big mistake with the `TStream`, and now you helped me again. I'm learn much to you. Thank you very much